# How to understand this proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have such expression

[image]

I have a questions to last three lines.

How from this line

$${(\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}) \cup (A \cap B) = (\bar{A} \cap C) \cup (A \cap \bar{C})}$$

we came to this one

$${C = \bar{B} \land \bar{C} = B}$$

There is a comment in from of this line `Communative Law` I surf a google a little and found a few explanation about this (ex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) law and there was nothing in common with this line.

> This law say in general `a * b = b * a`

and next question is how we actually came from this line

$${C = \bar{B} \land \bar{C} = B}$$

to this one

$${C = \bar{B}}$$

There is also a comment `Complement law`, a found an explation about this law and here also nothing in common

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)

So, question is - how to understand these last three lines? How we came from one to another and eventually to the end to prove?

Comment: The author equates the terms: $(A^c \cap B^c)$ and $(A^c \cap C)$ and the other pair. From it: $B^c=C$.

Comment: Obviously: $B = (B^c)^c= C^c$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What do you mean `From it: Bc=C`? How? `A + B + C` from it 123... what?? How? And about your second comment ` B = -(-B)` ok, but how do you came to `-C`? How do you assume that `B` and `C` could be equal?

Comment: That is what is written in the text...

Comment: The issue is that from the "equation", there is no reason why $B^c=C$; it can as well be $B=C$.

Comment: Well $\dots$ Communative Law was cite for
$$(A^c\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A)=(A\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap A^c)$$
$$\equiv(A^c\cap \color{orange}{B^c})\cup(A\cap \color{red}{B})=(A^c\cap \color{orange}{C})\cup(A\cap \color{red}{C^c})$$

Also note that $C=B^c\equiv C^c=B$, and clearly $C=B^c\land C^c=B\equiv C=B^c$

Comment: However I think the the main question is how could we have
$$(A^c\cap \color{orange}{B^c})\cup(A\cap \color{red}{B})=(A^c\cap \color{orange}{C})\cup(A\cap \color{red}{C^c})$$
$$\Rightarrow \color{orange}{C=B^c}\land \color{red}{C^c=B}$$

Comment: Suppose it's not the case, have the negation is $$(A^c\cap B^c)\cup(A\cap B)=(A^c\cap C)\cup(A\cap C^c)\text{ and } C\neq B^c\\$$
Then by the definition we have
\begin{align}
&x\in A^c\land x\in B^c\lor x\in A\land x\in B\leftrightarrow x\in A^c\land x\in C\lor x\in A\land x\in C^c\land\neg( x\in C\leftrightarrow x\in B^c)\\
\end{align}
Which clearly is a contradiction. I don't think you can prove this only use set identities.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is false.
A $\Delta$ B = A $\Delta$ B but B /= B$^c$.

A $\Delta$ B = A $\Delta$ C. implies B = C.
Proof.
Assune b in B.
Case b not in A.  b in A $\Delta$ B,
b in A $\Delta$ C and as a not in A, b in C.
Case b in A.  b not in A $\Delta$ B.
If b not in C, then b in A $\Delta$ C.
Thus b in A $\Delta$ B, a contradiction.
Consequently b in C.
In conclusion B subset C and by symmetry C subset B.
Equality ensues.